# Print multiple pages using PrintDocument

Tags: c#, printing

I have an issue regarding printing multiple pages using the code below. It always prints only the last page. Can you guys please help me?

```
using (var rasterizer = new PdfRasterizer(pdfInputPdf))
{
    // Create a JpegImageFormat object.
    var jpegImageFormat = new JpegImageFormat(100);

    // Create a FixedImageSize object with required width and height.
    var imageSize = new PercentageImageSize(400);

    // Save the image.
    var imageData = rasterizer.Draw(jpegImageFormat, imageSize);

    using (var pd = new PrintDocument())
    {
        var margins = new Margins(0, 40, 0, 40);
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;

        pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            PrintPage(text1, text2, imageData, pd, args);
                        };

        pd.Print();
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
   private static int counter = 0;
        private static void PrintPage(string text1, string text2, byte[][] imageData, PrintPageEventArgs args)
        {

            foreach (var b in imageData)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(b))
                {
                    var i = Image.FromStream(stream);

                    CreateNotApprovedWatermark(i, text1, text2);

                    if (args.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.CanDuplex)
                    {
                        args.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Horizontal;
                    }

                    var m = args.MarginBounds;

                    if (i.Width / (double)i.Height > m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
                    {
                        m.Height = (int)(i.Height / (double)i.Width * m.Width);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m.Width = (int)(i.Width / (double)i.Height * m.Height);
                    }
                    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
                    if (counter <= 2)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        args.HasMorePages = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        args.HasMorePages = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You cannot use foreach in the PrintPage event handler.  You need to do one element per page.  Add an index variable, use the BeginPrint event handler to set it to 0, increment it for each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a easy solution to my problem after quit some trial and error:

```
  using (var rasterizer = new PdfRasterizer(new Foxit.PDF.Rasterizer.InputPdf(pdfData)))
            {
                // Create a JpegImageFormat object.
                var jpegImageFormat = new JpegImageFormat(100);

                // Create a FixedImageSize object with required width and height.
                var imageSize = new PercentageImageSize(400);

                // Save the image.
                var imagePages = rasterizer.Draw(jpegImageFormat, imageSize);

                using (var pd = new PrintDocument())
                {
                    var margins = new Margins(0, 40, 0, 40);
                    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins;
                    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;
                    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;

                    var pageNumber = 0;

                    pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        PrintPage(pageNumber, text1, text2, imagePages[pageNumber], args);
                        if (pageNumber < imagePages.Count())
                        {
                            pageNumber++;
                            args.HasMorePages = pageNumber != imagePages.Count();
                        }
                    };

                    pd.Print();
                }
            }
```

The problem was placement of the `HasMorePages` property.